# How to resolve "unsupported" error from expect library

Tags: go

While trying out the library - https://github.com/Netflix/go-expect

Following the readme, I tried to execute their main program (from readme).
On the first line:

```
c, err := expect.NewConsole(expect.WithStdout(os.Stdout))
```

I get error : 2018/12/14 16:09:00 unsupported

I am using Windows 7. I am not sure what the error implies here. What is not supported? Does it not support Windows or its something else?

Answer (score 2):

The library (or at least the `expect.NewConsole` function) doesn't work with Microsoft Windows.

It uses the github.com/kr/pty package, which requires unix.

The "unsupported" error comes from this file: https://github.com/Netflix/go-expect/blob/master/vendor/github.com/kr/pty/pty_unsupported.go

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know another Go library that offers similar functionality but is compatible with Windows?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know of another Go library that does this.